# From what set are these brown, white, and pink parts?

Tags: set-identification

I would like to find the set these Lego bricks belong to.
Browns, whites, and two 8x8 blue plates.

[image]

Comment: The 2 _Light Bluish Gray Plate 8 x 8_ and 2 _Reddish Brown Plate 2 x 12_ have only ever appeared in [two sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?fromForm=Y&viewMulti=Y&itemType=P&itemNo1=41539&itemSeq1=2&colorID1=86&itemNo2=2445&itemSeq2=2&colorID2=88&itemNo3=&itemSeq3=&colorID3=&in=S), none of which has the depicted magenta and transparent bricks. Are you sure the bag is factory sealed?

Comment: @zovits After a bit more searching it appears those 8 x 8 plates are actually Bright Light Blue (see my answer below)

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be set [41153](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=41153-1) Ariel's Royal Celebration Boat.
The 8 x 8 plates appeared a bit more blue than Light Bluish Grey, so I [search](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?fromForm=Y&viewMulti=Y&itemType=P&itemNo1=6111&itemSeq1=1&colorID1=1&itemNo2=3065&itemSeq2=1&colorID2=50&in=S)ed for sets with White 1 x 10 Brick and Trans Dark Pink 1 x 2 Brick w/o Tube

[image: 41153 Ariel's Royal Celebration Boat]